# Enable or disable Headphone Jack Connector of an iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to know how to Enable or disable Headphone Jack Connector of an iPhone, with Xcode and Objective-C.

Even if the device is plug on.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Won't your users resent you turning off their headphones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple’s human interface guidelines for the implementation of iPad applications recommend that when either the docking connector or headphones are unplugged during audio playback that the audio be automatically paused and then resumed when the connection is reestablished. And not to completely disable the jack connector.

To detect Headphone connector you need to use `kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange` and you need to add `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>` this framework to your build.